# Incrementing `static int` causes SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, crash, segmentation-fault

I'm debugging a crash reported as:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR
```

The crash is happening on the line that does `numberOfFails++`.

The app uses `ASIHTTP`. I personally much prefer using `NSURLConnection`. I'd never automatically repeat a request for `NSURLConnection` if it failed because I've never seen it fail when it shouldn't. I'd rather just give the UI a refresh button or show a `UIAlertView` with a button to try again or something like that.

Anyway, to cooperate with other team members, I'm looking to fix this issue without replacing `ASIHTTP` with `NSURLConnection` for now.

The request is being started with something like:

```
- (void)getResources:(CLLocation *)location withQuery:(NSString *)query {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"https://example.com/"]];
    self.resourcesAPIRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [resourcesAPIRequest setPostValue:[Model instance].oauth_token forKey:@"oauth_token"];
    [resourcesAPIRequest setPostValue:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude] stringValue] forKey:@"latitude"];
    [resourcesAPIRequest setPostValue:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude] stringValue] forKey:@"longitude"];
    [resourcesAPIRequest setPostValue:query forKey:@"query"];
    [resourcesAPIRequest setDelegate:self];
    [resourcesAPIRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(resourcesAPIReturned:)];
    resourcesAPIRequest.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(getResources:withQuery:)), @"repeatSelector", location, @"argument1", query, @"argument2", nil];   
    [resourcesAPIRequest startAsynchronous];
}
```

One thing I noticed is `: <ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>` is not in the header file, but this callback method is still being called OK:

```
#define maximumNumberOfFails 50

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request {
    static int numberOfFails = 0;

    if (numberOfFails < maximumNumberOfFails) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:sleepTimeInSeconds];
        if ([request.userInfo objectForKey:@"argument2"]) {
            [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([request.userInfo objectForKey:@"repeatSelector"]) withObject:[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"argument1"] withObject:[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"argument2"]];
        } else if ([request.userInfo objectForKey:@"argument1"]) {
            [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([request.userInfo objectForKey:@"repeatSelector"]) withObject:[request.userInfo objectForKey:@"argument1"]];
        } else {
            [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([request.userInfo objectForKey:@"repeatSelector"])];
        }
        numberOfFails++;
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Problem" message:@"There was a problem connecting to the servers.  Please make sure you have an Internet connection." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        numberOfFails = 0;
    }
}
```

Also, I think that `static int numberOfFails` should be `static NSUInteger numberOfFails`. And, I noticed that the request is started with `startAsynchronous`. Is `static int numberOfFails` atomic? That may be why we're getting the error `SEGV_ACCERR` (Invalid permissions for mapped object).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem likely has nothing to do with your static variable.

Does `requestFailed:` execute on the main thread, or in a background thread?

If it's on a background thread, you'll need to use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:`.

If it's on the main thread, you may need to take a pass through the runloop before executing a new HTTP request.  To do that, use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, and pass '0.0' as the delay.

You'll notice that both those methods allow only a single method parameter.  Typically, you pass your parameters in a `NSDictionary` rather than try to parse out the number of parameters beforehand, like you're doing.